# what is the best way of filling map of struct in a function

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I have the following code:

```
mystruct
{
    std::string str;
    int x;
}

void main()
{
   std::map<int, mystruct> mymap;
   func(mymap);
}

void func(std::map<int, mystruct>& mmap)
{
   mmap[1].str = "bla";
   mmap[1].x = 5;
}
```

What is the best way to fill the map in the function? Is this way correct?
Is the struct defined on the stack or the heap?

Comment: Your code isn't valid C++, so there is nothing to worry about re. the map, the struct or "the heap".

Comment: yes - i can use c++11, why? is my way not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why your code is not valid compilable C++ code. I've tried to fix them in my example below but other than that I can't see anything particularly wrong with your way.

In C++11 you can initialize a `map` with an initializer list. Also, if you are initializing a new `map` it would be more idiomatic to use a return value instead of reference parameter:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct mystruct
{
    std::string str;
    int x;
};

std::map<int, mystruct> func()
{
   return {{1, {"bla", 5}}};
}

int main()
{
   auto myMap = func();
}
```

A `map` will allocate memory for the elements dynamically so the struct will be on the "heap".

Comment: thanks, but I know the values to insert to the map only on runtime, so i cant use an initializer list

Comment: @Shay Initializer list values don't need to be compile-time constant.

Comment: @Shay I think you need to show something closer to your actual code because there are many different ways of filling a list and the "best"  will depend on what you are actually trying to do. As it stands we can only really answer based on the code you have written or guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would be a common minimum descent way of doing. And no worries about de-allocation or heap.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct mystruct
{
   std::string str;
   int x;
   mystruct(int xx, string s) : x(xx), str(s){}
   mystruct() {}
};

void func(std::map<int, mystruct>& mmap, int k, mystruct v)
{
   auto itr = mmap.begin();
   if ((itr = mmap.find(k)) == mmap.end())
   {
      mmap.insert(pair<int, mystruct>(k, v));
   }
   else
   {
      mmap[k] = v;
   }

}

int main()
{
   std::map<int, mystruct> mymap;

   mystruct s(5, "bla");
   func(mymap, 1, s);

   // look up
   if (mymap.find(1) != mymap.end())
   {
      cout << "found";
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "not found";
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just `mmap.insert(std::map<int, mystruct>::value_type(k, v))`, which returns a pair iterator/bool, where `second` indicates successful insertion (the key did not exist)

Comment: thanks, but the values of the struct are known only an runtime and inside function func, so i need to create the struct inside function func

Comment: @Shay Then remove the parameters and do what you must inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

If `func` is meant to add elements to an existing map that may already contain elements and those elements shouldn't be removed, this is the best way:

```
void func(std::map<int, mystruct>& mmap)
{
   mmap[1] = { "bla", 5 };
}
```

Otherwise, if `func` is just supposed to fill (initialize) an empty map then this is the best way (provided you're using at least C++11, for the *move* of the return value):

```
std::map<int, mystruct> func()
{
   std::map<int, mystruct> mmap;
   mmap[1] = { "bla", 5 };
   return mmap;
   // you could also use list initialization here as shown in Chris Drew's answer
}
```

and

```
auto mymap = func();
```

In both cases, `mmap` is on the stack. Putting it on the heap would require a call to either `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`, or `new` (don't use it).

Comment: The `mmap` itself will be on the stack yes, but internally it will allocate memory for the elements on the heap. So the struct itself (which is what they asked) will be on the heap.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Oh right, true, I missed that part of the sentence somehow, thanks.